# Average every nth cell in a column including the first cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, average

Does anyone have a formula in excel to average every nth cell in a column including the first cell?

For example in the picture if I want to average every 5th cell in the A column it would come out to be 2.75.

[image: Excel Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resolving AVERAGE down to its component parts (i.e. SUM/COUNT),

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A16, (MOD(ROW(1:16), 5)=0)+(ROW(1:16)=1))/SUMPRODUCT((MOD(ROW(1:16), 5)=0)+(ROW(1:16)=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you also show me the formulas for SUM and COUNT? Thank you.

Comment: Split the above formula at the `/`. The first part is the sum, the latter the count.